# Как вшить в .exe двоичные данные, без использования массива unsigned char? Возможно ли?

Tags: c++

И без ресурсов.

Например, вместо

`char buf[] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0xff };`

Использовать например `.lib` файл, и чтобы при компоновке код из неё был частью программы.

Может я и сам уже ответил на вопрос, но, всё таки, как лучше сделать?

Comment: Непонятно, чем вас не устраивает обычная константа.

Comment: есть ресурсы (но это под windows в основном). Можно подклеить бинарный файл в конец exe.

Comment: Смотря для чего. Что Вы собираетесь с ними делать?